# Find ${51\choose 50} + {52\choose 49} + {53\choose 48} + … + {100\choose 1} + {101\choose 0}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

I know the answer is $F_{100}$, where $F_{100}$ is $100^{th}$ number in Fibonacci sequence. And it is, in general, true for any n, I checked it for some initial values. How can we prove this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2206150/using-binomial-theorem-to-calculate-nth-term-of-fibonacci-sequence

Comment: Yes, the proof can also be found here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fibonacci_Number_as_Sum_of_Binomial_Coefficients

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denote by $s_n$ such series:
$$s_n = C_n^0 + C_{n-1}^1+C_{n-2}^2 + ...$$
Then $s_0 = 1, s_1 = 1$, so by induction:
$$s_{n}+s_{n+1} = 1 + (C_{n}^0 +C_{n}^1) + (C_{n-1}^1 +C_{n-1}^2) + ... = C_{n+2}^0 + C_{n+2}^1 + C_{n+2}^2 + ... = s_{n+2}$$
The last equality is the property of Pascal's triangle.